# Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation ... do not change the publicly displayed post score

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

Downvoting an answer on ux.stackexchange.com I've received below message:

[image]

I've two question about it:

- right after that I've tried up-voting too, and it happened just correctly, without any message. Should the message state "Down-votes ..."?
  (it seems ironic to have this issue on a site discussing user experience:) )
- what "recorded" means here? if it's not displayed, neither affect reputation of anybody, what's the use of recording?

Comment: This is more of a network-wide issue than a UX.StackExchange one as this functionality is the same across all the Stack Exchange websites. There's a main Meta site for all StackExchange issues that covers some of these questions that you should be able to find specific answers to. This one for instance: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280779/voting-with-less-than-125-reputation-points

Comment: I'm not SE an developer, but I believe they use a static message with placeholder like "*Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than **{rep-needed}** reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.*" both for upvote (15 rep) and downvote (125 rep). As for "recorded", it's recorded as [anonymous feedback that can be seen on SE Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234828/is-the-count-of-anonymous-feedback-available-in-the-schema).